# cancel() or cancelAll() not dismissing notifications from application

Tags: java, android, android-notifications

In the android notification manager class there are the two functions cancel() and cancelAll() regardless of what i define the notifcationManager as i am still unable to cancel the notifications that are pushed. This notification service is running in a background service that is started when the app is opened.

````
 @Override
    public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn){
        Context context = this;
        HushNotification notif = new HushNotification(sbn);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) 

        getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        //this does not properly cancel the notifications posted
        notificationManager.cancelAll();


    } ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Put your code in the onCreate method:

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

notificationManager.cancelAll();
```

Comment: in which class? my background service?

Answer (score 0):

Put this in my notification on receive function in my notification service and it solved the problem

```
 cancelNotification(sbn.getKey());
 notificationManager.cancel(sbn.getId());
```